# Determine once on the last page to stop macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am scraping data from a webpage. Once on the last page, how do I get the macro to end?

For instance, if there are 4 pages of data, how do I stop and display the data scrape through the 4 pages?

There are 4 pages of data. I receive the 1004 run time error, if in the code I say

```
Do While i < 5
```

...

```
'Macro to query Delinquency Status Search for DFB Counties
'Run Monday to pull data from Friday

Sub queryActivityDailyMforF()

Dim nextrow As Integer, i As Long
Dim dates
dates = Date - 3

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Do While i < 4
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Page " & i
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=16&county_1=21&county_1=23&county_1=32&county_1=36&county_1=41&county_1=46&county_1=53&county_1=54&county_1=57&county_1=60&county_1=66&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
        Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))

        '.Name = _
        "2015&search_1.x=40&search_1.y=11&date=on&county_1=AL&lic_num_del=&lic_num_rep=&status=NS&biz_name=&owner_name="
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "10"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    'autofit columns
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'check for filter, if not then turn on filter
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").AutoFilter
    End If

i = i + 1

End With
Loop
Application.StatusBar = False

'Align text left
Cells.Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

If i = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you are parsing a series of webpages with incrementing page number.  You want a way to determine the number of pages the web results have so you can iterate over all of them?

Comment: Yes pretty much. Since I am not pulling from the whole web page, i am just pulling the specific counties that I need, I want to just iterate through those specific counties. There are times when the data for a county does not contain any data. I am looking for a way to determine once it hits the last page of data to end the code. Example, if there were 10 pages of data, and i have my do while set for i < 25, i want it so that the code will finish execution after scraping the data from page 10.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm sure there is a better answer** involving querying the table or getting an xml version of the results from the webmaster of the site, and **THIS IS NOT BEST PRACTICE** but you could use the error handler.  It should look like this, generically:

```
Sub Stuff()

    Do While True
        On Error Goto ErrHndl
        ErrorProneCode
    Loop

LoopExit:

    On Error Resume 0
    Non_ErrorProneCode

Exit Sub
ErrHndl:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
         Resume LoopExit
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
    End If
End Sub
```

In the sample above, if an error is throne by the `ErrorProneCode` sub, the script will jump to the `ErrHndl:` label.  There we check for the 1004 error and if that's the error we find, we resume at the `LoopExit:` label, and continue on.  It is advised that you disable your error handler by calling `On Error Resume 0` once you are executing code which you do not expect to break.